# Python os.isfile doesn't respect excel files

Tags: python, excel, path

```
ipdb> os.listdir(SPREADSHEETS_DIR)
['Report Mar.xlsx']
ipdb> fff = os.listdir(SPREADSHEETS_DIR)[0]
ipdb> fff
'Report Mar.xlsx'
ipdb> os.path.isfile(fff)
False
```

Why is that? I know I could check the extension, but isn't os.path.isfile supposed to work with such files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do `os.listdir(SPREADSHEETS_DIR)`, you get the contents of that directory directly. But these have to be interpreted relative to this path.

Try

```
ffg = os.path.join(SPREADSHEETS_DIR, fff)
ffg # to look at
os.path.isfile(ffg)
```

and you'll find out that it works.

(Note that I follow you in the process of using very bad variable names...)

Comment: True, actually I've just come across that, when I tried to delete fff. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ah, in reference to your side note - please note that I was using debugger prompt so I just created some random variable name. Normally I use more descriptive variable names :) )